Expected utility of a series of optimal decisions
I am tearing my hair out trying to find a solution to a problem, and the results I'm getting don't make sense to me.
Please bear with me for a moment, this will be long.
Let $\vec Z = (Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_T)$ be a sequence of $T$ i.d. binary outcomes of a certain process. For every $Z_i = 1$ I get $1$ utilon; otherwise, I get $0$.
Let $\vec D = (D_1, D_2, ..., D_T)$ be a sequence of decisions I can make, one after another, about the process that generates $\vec Z$, which can have values $o$ or $n$, and let $\theta$ and $\tau$ be two parameters whose values can range from $0$ to $1$ and for which I have a prior distribution.

If $D_i = n$, $Z_i = 1$ with probability $\theta$. Otherwise, $Z_i = 1$ with probability $\tau$.
If $D_{i - 1} = o$, then $D_i = o$; you cannot go back to $n$ once you decide $o$.
If $D_1 = n$, I pay a utility cost of $C$ at that point; otherwise I don't. That's in addition to the utility of $Z_1$, whatever it is.
If $D_{i - 1} = n$ and $D_i = o$, I pay a utility cost of $C$ again to switch back.
I only make decision $D_{i + 1}$ after making decision $D_i$ and observing outcome $Z_i$.

So any given series of decisions consists of some number $T_n$, which may be zero, of $n$s, followed by some number $T_o$, which may be zero, of $o$s, and $T_n + T_o = T$. The total utility of a given sequence of decisions and outcomes is:
$$U\left(\vec D = \vec d, \vec Z = \vec z\right) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^T z_i - \mathbb I\left[ T_n\left(\vec d\right) > 0 \right] \left(1 + \mathbb I\left[ T_n\left(\vec d\right) < T \right]\right)\ C$$
At each time step $i$, I want to make the "optimal" decision, which is to say the decision that maximises my remaining expected utility knowing that at each future step I will also be making optimal decisions.
Let $\vec D_i = \left(D_i, D_{i + 1}, ..., D_T \right)$ be all decisions from step $i$ onwards, $\vec Z_i = \left(Z_i, Z_{i + 1}, ..., Z_T \right)$ be all outcomes from step $i$ onwards, $\Delta_{i, k}$ be the optimal decision at step $i$ given that the decision at step $i - 1$ was $k$, and $\vec\Delta_{i, k} = \left(\Delta_{i, k}, \Delta_{i + 1, \Delta_{i, k}}, \Delta_{i + 2, \Delta_{i + 1, \Delta_{i, k}}}, ... \right)$ be the series of optimal decisions from step $i$ onwards given that the decision at step $i - 1$ was $k$. Then I can define functions $U_o$ and $U_n$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
U_o\left(\vec z_i \right) &= \sum\limits_{j = i}^T z_j \\
U_n\left(\vec d_i, \vec z_i \right) &=
\begin{cases}
-C + z_i + U_o\left(\vec z_{i + 1} \right) &\text{if } d_i = o\text{,}
\\
z_i + U_n\left(\vec d_{i + 1}, \vec z_{i + 1} \right)
&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
From which:
$$
\begin{aligned}
U\left(\vec d, \vec z \right) =
\begin{cases}
U_o\left(\vec z\right) &\text{if }d_1 = o\text{,}
\\
- C + U_n\left(\vec d, \vec z\right) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
The expected values of making a given first decision are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E_{\vec \Delta_2, \vec Z} \left[
U\left(d_1, \vec \Delta_2, \vec Z \right)
\right]
&=
\begin{cases}
\mathbb E_{\vec \Delta_2, \vec Z} \left[
U_o\left(\vec Z\right)
\middle| d_1 = o
\right]
&\text{if }d_1 = o\text{,}
\\
\mathbb E_{\vec \Delta_2, \vec Z} \left[
- C + U_n\left(d_1, \vec \Delta_2, \vec Z\right)
\middle| d_1 = n
\right]
&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
&=
\begin{cases}
\hat \tau\ T
&\text{if }d_1 = o\text{,}
\\
- C + \hat\theta +
\mathbb E_{\vec \Delta_2, \vec Z} \left[
U_n\left(\vec \Delta_2, \vec Z_2\right)
\middle| d_1 = n
\right]
&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\
\\
\mathbb E_{\vec \Delta_2, \vec Z} \left[U_n\left(\vec \Delta_2, \vec Z_2\right)\middle| d_1 = n \right]
&= 
\sum\limits_{\vec\delta_2, \vec z}
U_n\left(\vec \delta_2, \vec z_2\right)
\ P\left(\vec \delta_2, \vec z \middle| d_1 = n \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
It's that last probability term that really gets me. I think I must be making some mistake with it. Here's what I've got:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(\vec \delta_{i + 1}, \vec z_i \middle| d_i = n \right)
&=
\int\limits_0^1
\int\limits_0^1
P\left(\vec z_i \middle| \vec \delta_{i + 1}, d_i = n, \theta, \tau \right)
\ P\left(\vec \delta_{i + 1} \middle| d_i = n, \theta, \tau \right)
\ p(\theta, \tau)
\text{ d}\theta
\text{ d}\tau
\end{aligned}
$$
It seems to me like it should be the case that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(\delta_j \middle| \delta_{j - 1}, \delta_{j - 2}, ..., \delta_{i + 1}, d_i = n, \theta, \tau \right) &= P\left(\delta_j \middle| \delta_{j - 1}, \theta, \tau \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Because, if I know $\theta$ and $\tau$ with certainty and I know my previous decision, all other decisions should be irrelevant: my future expected utility only depends on $\theta$ and $\tau$. Then, looking at the last step:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E_{Z_T} \left[U_n\left(d_T, Z_T \right) \middle| \theta, \tau \right]
&= \begin{cases}
- C + \tau &\text{if } d_T = o \text{,}\\
\theta &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\
P\left(\delta_T = n \middle| d_{T - 1} = n, \theta, \tau \right)
&= P\left(\theta > - C + \tau \middle| d_{T - 1} = n, \theta, \tau \right) \\
&= \mathbb I\left[ \theta > - C + \tau \right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Next-to-last step:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E_{\Delta_T, \vec Z_{T - 1}} \left[U_n\left(d_{T - 1}, \Delta_T, \vec Z_{T - 1} \right) \middle| \theta, \tau \right]
&= \begin{cases}
- C + 2\ \tau &\text{if } d_{T - 1} = o \text{,}\\
\theta +
\mathbb E_{\Delta_T, \vec Z_{T - 1}} \left[U_n\left(\Delta_T, Z_T \right) \middle| \theta, \tau, d_{T - 1} = n \right]
 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
The expected utility at that last part over there would be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E_{\Delta_T, \vec Z_{T - 1}} \left[U_n\left(\Delta_T, Z_T \right) \middle| \theta, \tau, d_{T - 1} = n \right]
=\ 
& \sum\limits_{\delta_T, \vec z_{T - 1}}
U_n\left(\delta_T, z_T \right)
\ P\left(\delta_T, \vec z_{T - 1} \middle| \theta, \tau, d_{T - 1} = n \right) \\
=\ 
& \sum\limits_{\delta_T, \vec z_{T - 1}}
U_n\left(\delta_T, z_T \right)
\ P\left(\vec z_{T - 1} \middle| \delta_T, \theta, \tau, d_{T - 1} = n \right)
\ P\left(\delta_T \middle| \theta, \tau, d_{T - 1} = n \right)
\\
=\ 
& \sum\limits_{z_T}
U_n\left(o, z_T \right)
\ P\left(z_T \middle| \delta_T = o, \theta, \tau, d_{T - 1} = n \right)
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right]
\ +\\
& \sum\limits_{z_T}
U_n\left(n, z_T \right)
\ P\left(z_T \middle| \delta_T = n, \theta, \tau, d_{T - 1} = n \right)
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right]
\\
=\ 
& 
- C
\ \left(1 - \tau \right)
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right]
\ +\\
& 
(- C + 1)
\ \tau
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right]
\ +\\
& 
0
\ \left(1 - \theta \right)
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right]
\ +\\
& 
1
\ \theta
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right]
\\
=\ 
& 
(- C + \tau)
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right]
\ +\\
& 
\theta
\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right]
\end{aligned}
$$
So, for it to make sense to decide $n$ at the next-to-last step, we have to have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\theta + 
(- C + \tau)\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right] +
 \theta\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right]
&> - C +2\ \tau
\\
\theta + 
(- C + \tau)\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right] +
 \theta\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right]
&>
(- C +2\ \tau)\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right] +
(- C +2\ \tau)\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right] 
\\
(\theta - \tau)\ \mathbb I \left[\theta < - C + \tau \right] +
(2\ \theta + C - 2\ \tau)\ \mathbb I \left[\theta > - C + \tau \right]
&>
0
\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Which is to say that, if $\theta < - C + \tau$ (i.e. we will choose $o$ at the last step), then $\theta > \tau$, which is impossible; and conversely, if $\theta > - C + \tau$, it has to be the case that $\theta > - \frac C 2 + \tau$.
But that implies that the vector $\vec \delta_{T - 2} = (n, n, o)$ has probability zero!
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(\vec \delta_{T - 2} = (n, n, o)\right)
&= 
\int\limits_0^1
\int\limits_0^1
P\left(\delta_{T - 2} = n, \delta_{T - 1} = n, \delta_T = o \middle| \theta, \tau\right)
\ p(\theta, \tau)
\text{ d}\theta
\text{ d}\tau \\
&= 
\int\limits_0^1
\int\limits_0^1
P\left(\delta_T = o \middle| \delta_{T - 1} = n, \theta, \tau\right)
\ P\left(\delta_{T - 1} = n \middle| \delta_{T - 2} = n, \theta, \tau\right)
\ P\left(\delta_{T - 2} = n \middle| \theta, \tau\right)\ p\left(\theta,\tau\right)
\text{ d}\theta
\text{ d}\tau \\
&= 
\int\limits_0^1
\int\limits_0^1
\mathbb I \left(\theta < - C + \tau \right)
\ \mathbb I \left(\theta > - \frac C 2 + \tau \right)
\ P\left(\delta_{T - 2} = n \middle| \theta, \tau\right)
\ p(\theta, \tau)
\text{ d}\theta
\text{ d}\tau \\
\end{aligned} 
$$
That obviously can't be the case; even if I don't know what outcomes I'll observe in the future, there must be some chance that I'll observe outcomes that will make the best decision at some point in this decision chain to be $o$!
I assume I must've made some error in the conditional independence arguments, but I have no idea what, nor what the correct argument would be.
